# What happened to HttpResponseMessage in .NET 4.5, is there an alternative?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5

My project was building for .NET 4 and the version of `System.Net.Http` it was referencing was version 2. I just upgraded to .NET 4.5 because I wanted to do some of [this routing stuff](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/21/An-Introduction-to-ASPNET-Web-API) and it required me to reference version 4 of the `System.Net.Http` assembly which I did.

However, my webservices all return a `HttpResponseMessage` which doesn't exist in version 4 of the assembly.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per MSDN it's still in the System.Net.Http assembly.  Make sure that you are refrencing both the new System.Net and System.Net.Http assemblies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx

I created a new project and added the System.Net and System.Net.Http assemblies and the HttpResponseMessage showed up fine.

Comment: I see, adding `System.Net` version 4 made it work again (even though it's in `System.Net.Http`) however adding that library has broken something else with `MapHttpRoute`. I will look into it, thank you.

Comment: Rebuilding it I get this "Error 1 The type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0...." I thought it was fixed, but apparently not...

Comment: I think it's possible that because I converted the solution from .net 4 to .net 4.5 that it has gotten confused, any ideas on how to sort this mess out?

Comment: I've fixed it by deleting an obselete reference. The problem now is that HttpResponseMessage is different, it doesn't support `<T>` so I am still stuck on converting the code across.

Comment: Is there any reference to "System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0..." in your web.config file under the assemblies section?  If so remove it.

Comment: Check out this post on the missing generic HttpResposneMessage  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/355170, aparently it was removed because it wasn't type safe.

Comment: Cheers, what I have done is started a new project from scratch and it has fixed pretty much all of the issues. The last issue with the removal of the generic HttpResponseMessage I found a simple solution for, thanks :)

Comment: @NibblyPig - and what was this simple solution?

regards,
The Necromancer

Comment: @pentaphobe Hmm this was 4 years ago! There is another way to create a response message, something like `request.CreateHttpResponse()` but I can't remember off hand.